# Benchmarks command error

Tags: benchmarking

need help with benchmarking: the command `cargo build --release --features runtime-benchmarks` completes without any problem, but then I try  `./target/release/fs-node benchmark pallet --chain dev --execution wasm --wasm-execution compiled --pallet pallet_nft --extrinsic "*" --steps 100 --repeat 40 --output ./pallets/nft/src/weights.rs --template ./pallets/roles/src/frame-weight-template.hbs` and I get  this :  `Error: Input("NotPermitted")` any idea about the source of this error?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe your shell interpolates the `--extrinsic "*"` to something else. Try leaving it empty by `'--extrinsic='`, or try a specific extrinsic for testing.  
If that does not help, please share the code so I can try it as well.

Comment: It only does it with a particular pallet (nft pallet). the code is here: https://github.com/Fair-Squares/fair-squares/blob/96-pallet-onboarding/pallets/nft/src/benchmarking.rs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case the error originates from your pallet logic itself.
The `NotPermitted` error is defined [here](https://github.com/Fair-Squares/fair-squares/blob/f5207c4a74b362cb46be368240c9489280ce095b/pallets/nft/src/lib.rs#L260).
In your benchmark you call the `mint` extrinsic with this account: `create_account::<T>("caller", 0)` which is not permitted to mint, therefore the error.
The `can_mint` function in the `Permissions` trait guards that, you can either mock it by whitelisting that account or use an account that is permissioned.

With mocked `Permissions` it looks like this for the `mint` extrinsic but the others need fixing as well.

```
Pallet: "pallet_nft", Extrinsic: "mint", Lowest values: [], Highest values: [], Steps: 100, Repeat: 40
Raw Storage Info
========
Storage: NftModule Collections (r:1 w:0)
Storage: Uniques Asset (r:1 w:1)
Storage: Uniques Class (r:1 w:1)
Storage: Uniques CollectionMaxSupply (r:1 w:0)
Storage: Uniques Account (r:0 w:1)
Storage: NftModule Items (r:0 w:1)

Median Slopes Analysis
========
-- Extrinsic Time --

Model:
Time ~=    48.62
              µs

Reads = 4
Writes = 4

Min Squares Analysis
========
-- Extrinsic Time --

Model:
Time ~=    48.62
              µs

Reads = 4
Writes = 4
```

Two more things just for your convenience:

1. You can run the benchmarks in a *test* mode where just one iteration is executed. This compiles much faster than the normal benchmarking. The test mode uses the mocked runtime and the real benchmarks use the node runtime.

```sh
cargo t --features=runtime-benchmarks -p pallet-nft
```

2. In the long run you should try to get rid of the `without_storage_info` annotation. *Just* delete them and fix the compile errors. In the future these annotations need to be removed to enable PoV benchmarking.

Comment: Thank you!! It totally makes sense!! and thank you for the additional advices!!!